# ImageResizer 'Use .Build(new Image Job(source, dest, settings, dispose Source, add FileExtension)).Final Path instead'

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm using imageresizer, it works very well at run time:

```
foreach (string fileKey in Request.Files.Keys)
            {
                //Skip unused file controls.
                var file = Request.Files[fileKey];
                if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; 

                //Get the physical path for the uploads folder and make sure it exists
                string desFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Data/ProductImages/") + productId.ToString();
                if (!Directory.Exists(desFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(desFolder);

                //string fileName;
                string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                //Generate each version
                foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
                {
                    //Generate a filename (GUIDs are best).
                  string  filePath = Path.Combine(desFolder, guid  + suffix);

                    //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
                ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, filePath, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true); 
                }
```

but get this warning from visual studio

> ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(object, object, Image Resizer.Resize
>   Settings, bool, bool)' is obsolete: 'Use .Build(new Image Job(source,
>   dest, settings, dispose Source, add FileExtension)).Final Path
>   instead'

how fix it?

Comment: i have the same problem . do you remmber what was the type of the "file"?

Comment: @ZivDaniel PostedFile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use `.Build(new Image Job(source, dest, settings, dispose Source, add FileExtension))` as the deprecation warning suggests.

Replace

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, filePath, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true);
```

with

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file,filePath, new Instructions(versions[suffix]),false,true))
```