# C# - resizing and cropping images using ImageResizer

Tags: c#, imageresizer

**Code**

```
ResizeSettings resizeCropSettings = new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=150&format=jpg&crop=auto");

         string fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, newFile, resizeCropSettings, false, true);
```

and the message says use :

> .Build(new ImageJob(source, dest, settings, disposeSource, addFileExtention)).FinalPath  instead.

Anyone can explain what does this mean ? and please give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Here: [ImageResizer 'Use .Build(new Image Job(source, dest, settings, dispose Source, add FileExtension)).Final Path instead'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325525/imageresizer-use-buildnew-image-jobsource-dest-settings-dispose-source-a)

Check which version you are using.

Replace

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, filePath, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true);
```

with

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file,filePath, new Instructions(versions[suffix]),false,true))
```

You will get that error described in your comment if

CAUSE

```
You didn’t install the assembly specified in the error.
Your DLL depend on other DLL’s to get its job done and if you didn’t copy or install those too, you’d indeed get this error message.
Or you have installed an older version of the assembly.
This error occurs often when we use C# HelperClass to support the orchestrations, but can occur in other situations.
```

SOLUTION

```
Make sure that you have the last version of the assembly installed.

Rebuild the solution.
Deploy the correct solution.
```

Comment: I tried it but I am having an error that says: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Instructions' from assembly 'imageResizer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Are you using ImageResizer.Mvc instead of ImageResizer 4.0.4? ImageResizer.Mvc is deprecated

Comment: oh yes I am using it with MVC

Answer (score 0):

The message is already pretty clear, it means you need to replace

```
...Build(file, newFile, resizeCropSettings, false, true);
```

with

```
var lImageJob = new ImageJob(...);

...Build(lImageJob);
```

Comment: can you explain please ? i mean give me an example.

Comment: @aboodmanna An example can be found here: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/howto/upload-and-resize

Comment: I am having an error that says: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Instructions' from assembly 'imageResizer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: I think yes i installed the first nugget file